# Can I declare an array and assign an initial value for its first element only?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   float b;
   int c;
} Hello;

Hello hello[100];
```

I know I can assign value to the first element of this array:

```
hello[0] = {1,2.0,3};
```

but how to assign the first element when we declare the `hello: Hello hello[100];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requires additional set of `{}` (outer `{}` for the array, inner set(s) for the elements of the array):

```
Hello hello[100] = { {1, 2.0, 3} };
```

Comment: Note that the remaining 99 elements will be implicitly initialized to {0, 0.0, 0}; that's the rule when there are fewer initializers than elements in the array.

Answer (score 5):

Use this snippet:

```
Hello hello[100] = {{1, 2.0, 3}};
```

Outer braces initialize array, but there is only element in these braces - your first array element. And consequently you initialize hello[0] with the value inside of the outer braces.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports **c99** features then you can use **Designated Initializers** to initialize any element of an array.

```
Hello hello[100] = {[0] = {1,2.0,3}}, [98] = {2,3.5,4} };
```

This will initialize *0th* element to `{1,2.0,3}` and *98th* element to `{2,3.5,4}`.Others will be initialized to `{0,0.0,0}` it self. Another advantage of this method is that, order in which the elements are listed no longer matters i.e you may initialize above array as

```
Hello hello[100] = {[98] = {2,3.5,4}, [0] = {1,2.0,3} };
```